# PMD Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse

I have installed PMD for eclipse 3.8 in the debian successfully. However, I am following these (http://www.eclipsezone.com/articles/pmd/) instructions to test a simple check and I get not violation, warnings, errors, etc...despite that the plugin in enabled through Properties -> PMD. Am I missing something in the configuration ?

Answer (score 1):

The normal problem here is that your problems view is not instrumented the right way. Do the following steps to correct it:

1. Call the drop-down-menu [image] and select "Configure Contents..."
2. Ensure that all items are shown, or that your selection includes the PMD errors [image]
3. Accept your configuration change, and control, if the PMD infos, warnings, and errors are now visible.

Comment: No luck with that, everything is already selected the truth is that my project is in maven and I do not know if PMD can cooperate with maven.

Comment: It does not even seem to work with Java projects. Is it supposed to have such a tricky configuration ?

Answer (score 1):

Unlike FindBug or CheckStyle, the PMD Eclipse plug-in does not configure which rules to check for by default. You have to manually check which rules to use by going to Eclipse Preferences -> PMD -> Rule Configuration

[image: PMD Rule Configuration]

Answer (score 0):

I have also installed PMD as per instruction provided at

> http://www.eclipsezone.com/articles/pmd/

Its working fine for me i am able to genrate PMD reports, find the violation result.

What was the exact error are you getting.

Note : I have downloded PMD eclipse 3 plugin

Comment: I do not get any particular error, there is nothing in the violations tabs when I do Project->right click->PMD->check code...

Comment: The information will come in violations Overview.If your are not getting means everything will be correct in that project

Comment: Yes, but the example in eclipse zone is supposed to have a couple of violations. (Ying and Yang classes)